# Is there a way to update one html element that updates across all documents?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have an index.html page with a nav menu and I have 15 other html pages with the exact same menu.

Is it possible with html/css/js to update ONE file (say the index.html file), and all the updates are applied throughout all 15 documents?

I know you can do this with PHP but the page that I'm running doesn't use a PHP index file so I'm looking for another way.

Perhaps there's some other way to achieve this? Angular JS maybe? Any suggestions or links you can suggest to read/learn how to do this?

Comment: js templates - look @ mustache.js

Comment: someone gave an iframe solution already, you can also use `server side includes`, they still work, but it is almost certainly more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: you can also use javascript and fill an [ANY] element dynamically.  think I need more information to make any recommendation for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronizing tabs is available through `localStorage` and the `StorageEvent`. More info you can find on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent)

Once your `nav` is updated, you are calling `localStorage.setItem(someKey, someValue)`, and with the `window.addEventListener('storage', this.handleStorageEvent)` handling the change of the `localStorage` on other tabs. Tab on which the event was fired will not propagate the change of `localStorage`.

Hope my answer helped :3

Answer (score 1):

To do this JUST with HTML, you could use an iframe, with `<a target="_parent">`:

nav.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/" target="_parent">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html" target="_parent">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then include that in places with

```
<iframe src="/nav.html"></iframe>
```

Remember that the contents of an iframe should still be a valid HTML document, so you'll want a doctype, a head, a body, and CSS includes in nav.html too. Iframes also typically come with some default border and padding styles you'll need to get rid of.

---

However I would be amiss if I didn't say that the typical way of actually accomplishing this is by using a server side language such as PHP to dynamically build the menu on each page.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by XML http request... you just need to define all navigation header,menu in one file and refer with one div in all pages...

```
<html>
<script>
function includeHTML() {
var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
/*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
 z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
 for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
 elmnt = z[i];
/*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
file = elmnt.getAttribute("include-html");
if (file) {
  /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
      if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
      /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
      elmnt.removeAttribute("include-html");
      includeHTML();
    }
  }      
  xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
  xhttp.send();
  /*exit the function:*/
  return;
  }
 }
};
```

```
<script>
includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's possible and a requirement for any kind of non-trivial sized site.

The general way of doing such things without getting too sophisticated is this. In your HTML files you include some templates. Those templates control the general look and feel of your site. All of your HTML files include the same templates. If you want something different on a particular page you override your templates in that particular html file.

It ends up looking like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/include/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    my content in here.
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your `style.css` and your `custom.js` you can go to town customizing. You can add more stylesheets and more javascript scripts as needed. Most sites have more style and javascript than content. A lot more.

My favorite site to learn about these technologies is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web), but there are plenty of other great resources too.

Comment: BTW, I stripped out anything not needed to demonstrate the concept. You still can put in things like `<title>...`

Comment: Oh - and another great resource is going to whatever site you like and seeing how they are doing it. I use Chrome for my browser so I 'right-click' on what I want to learn about and choose 'inspect.'

Answer (score 1):

Include that nav as a snippet through all the pages, so eventually you will update one file and all the other pages will have these updates too. 
Check for more https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: This looks like a good way to do it. Thanks a bunch I will try it. Lots of decent answers here that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Haven't done that practically by myself but I think that should do the work, let me know if it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <div id="sideBar">
       <!-- every page needs to have this -->
    </div>
    <div id ="content">
    </div>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("sideBar").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="side.html" ></object>';

</script>
```

Can you use JQuery? :D

Example Page 1:

```
<div id="sideBar">
   <!-- every page needs to have this -->
</div>
<div id ="content">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#sideBar").load("side_content.html");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I can use jQuery this actually looks pretty simple. I was going to use the html include documentation from w3schools, but this looks faster.

Comment: @Nick0989 Great! Don't forget to mark it as the answer then ;-)